# maya python script erroring with object not found

Tags: python, maya

I'm trying to write a basic rename tool that has specific parameters to choose from and also a name field to type the name of the object, the ui and everything work fine its on button press I get an error saying `line 107: Object 'preFlightCheckUI|columnLayout13|frameLayout57|rowColumnLayout27|textField26' not found. #`

Not sure what Im doing wrong here? Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks!

```py
def build_asset_def(window, main_layout02):

    assetDef = cmds.frameLayout(label='Define Asset Name', width= 300, height= 400, collapsable= True, parent= main_layout02)

    baf = cmds.rowColumnLayout(numberOfColumns= 2, columnWidth= [(1,150), (2,150)], columnOffset= [(1, 'both', 5), (2, 'both', 5)], parent= assetDef)

    #text labels
    cmds.text(label='Define Project Name:', align= 'right', font= 'boldLabelFont', height= 30, parent= baf) 


    pre_proj_name = cmds.optionMenu()
    prefix_menu_items01 = ['DRAGON', 'BATMAN']

    for label_01 in prefix_menu_items01:
        cmds.menuItem(pre_proj_name, label= label_01)

    cmds.text(label='\tDepartment Name:\t', align= 'right', font= 'boldLabelFont', height= 30, parent= baf) 

    dep_name = cmds.optionMenu(label= 'Prefix:\t')
    menu_items02 = ['MOD', 'LookDev','Texture', 'Proxy']

    for label_02 in menu_items02:
        cmds.menuItem(dep_name, label= label_02)

    cmds.text(label='\tAsset Type:\t', align= 'right', font= 'boldLabelFont', height= 30, parent= baf)  

    asset_type = cmds.optionMenu()
    menu_items03 = ['Char', 'Enviro','Prop']

    for label_03 in menu_items03:
        cmds.menuItem(asset_type, label= label_03)

    cmds.text(label='\tAsset Name:\t', align= 'right', font= 'boldLabelFont', height= 30, parent= baf)

    asset_name = cmds.textField(text= '')

    cmds.text(label='\tMaterial ID:\t', align= 'right', font= 'boldLabelFont', height= 30, parent= baf) 

    suffix_material_type = cmds.optionMenu()
    suffix_menu_material_id = ['Skin', 'Teeth','Gums', 'Dirt']

    for label in suffix_menu_material_id:
        cmds.menuItem(suffix_material_type, label= label)

    applyBttn = cmds.button(label= 'Rename', height= 50, width= 300, command= partial(name_obj, pre_proj_name, dep_name, asset_type, asset_name, suffix_material_type))

def name_obj(prefix_element, suffix_element, depart_element, type_element, asset_name_element, *args):

    prefix = cmds.optionMenu(prefix_element, query= True, value= True)
    suffix = cmds.optionMenu(suffix_element, query=True, value= True)
    department = cmds.optionMenu(depart_element, query=True, value= True)
    assetType = cmds.optionMenu(type_element, query= True, value= True)
    assetName = cmds.textField(asset_name_element, query= True, text= True)

    name_template = '{prefix}_{department}_{type}_{new_name}_{suffix}_{index}'

    for i, obj in enumerate(cmds.ls(selection= True)):
        new_object_name = name_template.format(prefix=prefix, department= department, type= assetType, new_name= assetName, suffix= suffix, index= i)
        cmds.rename(obj, new_object_name)
```

Comment: Please update your code in a way it is formatted correctly.

Comment: I heavily recommend to use classes for UI. Keep every layout name inside your class. Makes everything easier to handle and you do not loose any variables.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Is that better? Or did you mean the format of the code itself?

Comment: Im still pretty new to python, so havent tried using classes yet but will look into it thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error comes from a inconsistent naming of your variables what leads to confusion. You try to query a text field with the variable `asset_name_element` from the last position of your function, but you call the function with `suffix_material_type` as last argument what is an option menu. I recommend to use the same variable names, then it becomes obvious what's wrong. Better, use a class with class variables, then it becomes heavier to exchange these values without intention.